# Linear equations Systems and parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Consider
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 4 & 3\\
3 & 6 & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$

a) Wich is the range of $A$ in fuction of $a\in \mathbb{R}$?

b) What terms have to satisfy $b \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ for the equation system $Ax=b$ has solution, with $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ ? How it depends on $a\in \mathbb{R}$?

For a) I did elemental operations and we have that the equivalent matrix is
$$R=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & a-9
\end{pmatrix}$$
but it doesn't matter wich is the value of $a$ because $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & a-9 \end{pmatrix}= (a-9)\begin{pmatrix}  0 & 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$, so the $range(A)=2$ always , or Am I wrong? Maybe I didn't uderstand the problem.

Comment: The range of $A$ is the set of all linear combinations of the columns of $A$. For example, $(1,2,3)$ is in the column space, and so are $(6,6,2a) = 2*(3,3,a)$ and $(3,6,9) = (1,2,3) + (2,4,6)$.

Comment: I thought that we have the Range(A)=Range(rows of A) and the range(columns of A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  The range is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$. So for each $a$, we get a two-dimensional subspace, $V_a=\{(x+3y,2x+3y,3x+ay):x,y\in\Bbb R\}$.  (The dimension is two because that is the rank.)

On $b)$, we have that $b$ must be in the range, which is the answer from $a)$.  Thus we need $b=(x+3y,2x+3y,3x+ay)$ for some $x,y\in\Bbb R$.  Say $b=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$.  Then we can get $x$ and $y$ in terms of $b_1$ and $b_2$.  We have $\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\2&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{pmatrix}$.  You can solve for this because the matrix is invertible, and then get $b_3$ in terms of $b_1,b_2$ and $a$ (since $b_3=3x+ay$).

Comment: I get it know, written a) would be:
Because the range is the column space of $A$, we have that the second column is the double of the firt column so, the range is two and the space is generate for two columns: $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\  2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\  3 \\ a \end{pmatrix}$ and for every $a$ we have the two-dimensional subspace.

Comment: You're on the right track.  More precisely, the range is two-dimensional.

Comment: Yeah, I was confused at first because, for the dimension of the rows spaces we have the two -dimensional but I  didn't know how to connect it with the $a$. 

for b) Is like you said, we got $b_{3}=3(b_{1}+b_{2}-2b_{1})+a\left(\frac{2b_{1}-b_{2}}{3}\right)$.

Comment: Good, good, good.